# How to pass $$variables to view from controller in CakePHP?

Tags: php, cakephp, variables

in AppController:

```
function beforeFilter() {

    $company = 'name of Company';

    $this->set(compact('company'));

}
```

in Controller class:

```
function companyinfo() {
    $logo = '<div><?php $this->Html->image('logo'); ?></div>';
    $welcome = 'welcome to $$company!';

    $this->set(compact('logo','welcome'));
}

function beforeFilter() {
    parent::beforeFilter();
}
```

in View class:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <?php echo $logo; ?>
        <?php echo $welcome; ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

it doesn't answer variable in view after passing the variable from AppController via controller..

Comment: What does "it doesn't answer variable" mean? That's pretty unclear.

Comment: like it show blank... no show variable...

Comment: Why did you call it "view class"?

Answer (score 2):

1)  When you use `$this->set(compact('company'));`, it is NOT setting a variable for use in any controller - it's passing `$company` to the view.

2) You're trying to write PHP code in a string, using a Helper (which are only available in Views)

```
$logo = '<div><?php $this->Html->image('logo'); ?></div>';
```

3) It's unusual to want to pass data from AppController to Controller to View.

What you probably want to do is something like this:

```
//App Controller 
function beforeFilter() {
    $company = 'name of Company';
    $this->set(compact('company'));
}

//Controller
function companyinfo() {
    $logo = 'logo';
    $this->set(compact('logo'));
}

//Layout file (or view file, but I assume it's layout since you're getting data in the AppController)
<?php
echo '<div>' . $this->Html->image($logo) . '</div>';
echo "Welcome to " . $company;
```

I mean this in the most constructive way possible (we've all been there).  It seems like you're struggling with some general PHP concepts.  Before you get too heavy into CakePHP, I recommend trying out a few lengthy tutorials in generic PHP - then when you feel completely comfortable with it, dive into CakePHP.

Comment: one quick question.. how about in view: `<?php $welcome = 'Welcome to $$company'; ?> <html><body><?php echo $welcome; ?></body></html>` ??

Comment: I really don't know what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

To get company into the view you can set it in your appcontroller if you want it avaiable in ALL views throughout your site or inside a specific controller if you only want it available in the view of the function you set it inside of. Either way you'll need to make correct use of the set function. For example:

`$this->set('company', 'Name of Company');`

OR

```
$company = 'Name of Company';
$this->set('company', $company);
```

Afterwards you'll be able to access the `$company` variable in the view.

`echo $company;` outputs `Name of Company`

As for your question for Dave:

```
<?php $welcome = 'Welcome to $$company'; ?> <html><body><?php echo $welcome; ?></body></html>
```

would be written as:

```
<html><body><?php echo "Welcome to ". $company; ?></body></html>
```

However, you should really look into using [layouts](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views.html#layouts) with cakephp so you don't need to the `<html>, <head>, <body>, etc.` tags in every view file